# How does Gitlab merge commits when branch is not rebased?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Let's say a branch has commits

```
X
B
A
```

And say master has commits

```
D
C
B
A
```

When I hit merge, does Gitlab automatically rebase and merge the branch into master?

After merging does it look like this?

```
X
D
C
B
A
```

Comment: See my https://www.biteinteractive.com/understanding-git-merge/ to learn what a merge is.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly GitLab does when you hit "merge" depends on the merge settings of your project.

It could rebase the branch onto master (as depicted in the question), or create an actual merge commit.

The possible settings are explained here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/methods/

Answer (score 0):

No. Your final diagram is impossible (X cannot literally change its parent from B to D), but if it represents anything it would probably be a picture of the branch after a rebase, *not* a merge (with X copied as `X'`), or a so-called "rebase-merge":

```
X' (branch if normal rebase, master if "rebase-merge")
D
C
B
A
```

A merge would create a new commit on `master` with X and D as its parents (and the branch itself would be unchanged):

```
            M (master)
           / \
 (branch) X   D
           \  |
            \ C
             \|
              B
              |
              A
```

Comment: I think you should add a simple chart there, @matt, to make it clear

Comment: @mkrieger1 Agreed, and that is what my answer implies.

Comment: @matt OP's final diagram is impossible if an actual merge is used, but I suspect there are settings where a "merge" is done by rebasing, just like when you use GitHub's "Rebase and merge" option for a PR. My guess is that's what OP is trying to figure out.

Comment: @joanis Totally, and I think your answer is good for grappling with that. I'm just trying to straighten out the _correct_ use of the terms "rebase" and "merge"; the thing GitHub does is falsely termed a "merge", and I presume GitLab uses the same sort of misleading terminology — which is what my answer attempts to combat.